# Android Bluetooth Libraries which make life easy?

Tags: android, bluetooth

What Android Bluetooth libraries are there which make BT easy to implement?

Yes, I've read [Android's Official BlueTooth Page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), yes I've read 400+ lines from [Android's BluetoothChat Example.](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) Whilst both of these resources are helpful, I'd very much like to know if the community knows of any Android Libraries, like Ketai ( google.com/p/ketai/ ), which make the BlueTooth protocol easy to implement.

Thanks in advance,

TH

Comment: How is it offtopic to ask the technological community what small-and-obscure libraries they know of to make it easier to implement something? My question is broad because if I was otherwise too specific, I'd be slammed for not doing my own work. All I need to know, is what libraries do you know of which make it very very easy to connect two phones over BT? I'll do the rest, thanks!

Comment: Because we don't allow library requests here.  Read the FAQ.  The reason is because its 100% opinion based as to what libraries are "good enough".  Suggesting a library is acceptable as an answer, but it isn't for a question.

Comment: As for it being too broad-  because "How do I bluetooth" is so completely dependant on what you're trying to do between the devices.  An answer that's fine for chat is completely wrong for printing.  Or for playing audio.  Or for transferring files.  ANy library that could be given as an answer would be wrong, because there's no way for a library to encompass all of bluetooth with its hundreds of sub-protocols.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/134) list of Bluetooth libraries. It is a comprehensive list and overview of (mostly) open source Bluetooth Android libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think Android Arsenal provide a very valuable and valid service in trying to advertise community produced libraries which otherwise may get little attention.

The two libraries I've seen on there are:

SimpleBluetoothLibrary - minSDK is to high, I need backward compatability

Android Bluetooth Library - Looks promising, I will investigate.

Comment: @TreeHugger have you found good library for ble to work with